# Spotbugs mvn plugin missing classes needed for analysis

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, spotbugs

I'm using a GitLab CI/CD Pipeline that uses the spotbugs plugin for Maven; when I try to run

```
mvn compile spotbugs:check
```

I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Fork Value is true
    [java] The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
    [java]   org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
```

The previous command works on my local machine, but fails on the GitLab runner. I suppose this may be a configuration problem (ie: something wrong on my pom.xml file) but I am not quite sure how to fix it.

Here is **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accessing-data-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accessing-data-mysql</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit 5, unit test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
            <version>${spring.version}</version> 
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven checkstyle plugin  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven spotbugs plugin  -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
              <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.12.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven PMD plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>add-integration-test-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <sources>
                        <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                      </sources>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>add-integration-test-resource</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <resources>
                        <resource>
                          <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                      </resources>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <!-- target/docker-spring-boot.jar -->
        <finalName>docker-spring-boot</finalName>

    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Show your pom.xml.

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/pduBp4vy